# Validate text in a text field with a keyword in an array and show a form if it is correct

Tags: javascript

Trying to take what a user enters into a text field and validate that keyword with an existing keyword (case sensitive) in an array to show a button on the page.

```
<input type="textfield" id="myCheck">  Enter the code <button onclick="myFunction()">Check</button>

<form action="https://www.example" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id">
<input type="image" id="text" style="display:none"  src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.exapmle.com/button.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>

     <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var keyWords = ["cat","dog","test"]
        // Get the checkbox
       var textBox = document.getElementById("myCheck").val();
        // Get the output text
       var text = document.getElementById("text");

        // If the checkbox is checked, display the output text
          if (textBox.val() == keyWords){
             text.style.display = "block";
          } else {
              text.style.display = "none";
           }
         }
    </script>
```

Comment: So what is the problem..?

Comment: Fine answers but no response from the author.

Answer (score 0):

You are making two mistakes

- You are using `val()` which is jQuery method and not the method of `HTMLElement`. You can access the value using `.value`
- Second problem is that you are comparing array `keyWords` with `value`. You should check whether its present in array or not using [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```js
function myFunction() {
            var keyWords = ["cat","dog","test"]
        // Get the checkbox
       var textBox = document.getElementById("myCheck").value;
        // Get the output text
       var text = document.getElementById("text");

        // If the checkbox is checked, display the output text
          if (keyWords.includes(textBox)){
             text.style.display = "block";
          } else {
              text.style.display = "none";
           }
         }
```

```html
<input type="textfield" id="myCheck">  Enter the code <button onclick="myFunction()">Check</button>

<form action="https://www.example" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id">
<input type="image" id="text" style="display:none"  src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.exapmle.com/button.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the function to next:

```
 <script>
    function myFunction() {
        var keyWords = ["cat","dog","test"]
    // Get the checkbox
   var textBox = document.getElementById("myCheck").value;
    // Get the output text
   var text = document.getElementById("text");

    // If the checkbox is checked, display the output text
      if (keyWords.IndexOf(textBox) > -1){
         text.style.display = "block";
      } else {
          text.style.display = "none";
       }
     }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `.val()` is used for jquery objects. Since you are getting element with native `getElementById` you should use `value` property to get the value.
2. To check if value is one of `keyWords` you can use `.includes` method.

Check out my solution below.

```js
var keyWords = ["cat","dog","test"]
// Get the checkbox
var textBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");
// Get the output text
var text = document.getElementById("text");
  
function myFunction() {
  // If the checkbox is checked, display the output text
  if (keyWords.includes(textBox.value)){
    text.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    text.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="textfield" id="myCheck">  Enter the code <button onclick="myFunction()">Check</button>

<form action="https://www.example" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id">
<input type="image" id="text" style="display:none"  src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.exapmle.com/button.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using vanilla js DOM, and not jquery, you can't use .val(), you should use "value"

also, textBox is already the text value, in the condition line 19, you don't need to recall .val()

Finally to check if  a value is in an array or not you can use the method array.includes(value)

A working fiddle, after fixing your code:

```html
<input type="textfield" id="myCheck">  Enter the code <button onclick="myFunction()">Check</button>

<form action="https://www.example" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id">
<input type="image" id="text" style="display:none"  src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.exapmle.com/button.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>

     <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var keyWords = ["cat","dog","test"]
        // Get the checkbox
       var textBox = document.getElementById("myCheck").value;
        // Get the output text
       var text = document.getElementById("text");

        // If the checkbox is checked, display the output text
          if (keyWords.includes(textBox) ){
             text.style.display = "block";
          } else {
              text.style.display = "none";
           }
         }
    </script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kLmcfvp4/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the ONINPUT event to check letter by letter as they are typed by the user:

```js
//The javascript logic to see if it matches will look like this...

function CheckInput(S) {
  var Secret = 'apples';

  if (S === Secret) {
    alert('You got it!');
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="textfield" id="myCheck" oninput="CheckInput(this.value);">
```